# How add svg custom icon ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

how to add custom icon ionic 2, i have svg file i need add the icon in menu

```
this.pages = [
      {icon: 'Test', title: 'Logout', component: LoginPage }
    ];

    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        <ion-icon name="{{p.icon}}" svgversion item-left></ion-icon>
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
```

layout.scss

```
ion-ion[name="test"][svgversion] {
  content: url("../../img/accountsDeposits.svg");
}
```

Comment: You just add it in `theme/app.core.scss` file using `@font-face` and use it anywhere where you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fontastic](http://fontastic.me/) to create svg icon fonts from your svg icons, you can use it online or export to your own svg fontface, it gives you instructions on how to use it, its FREE

[Follow link](http://fontastic.me/)

Answer (score 0):

You just add in `/src/theme/global.scss` or `/page/your-page/your-page.scss`:

```
.logo {

    background: url(../assets/images/logo-vc.svg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 80px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;

}
```